# Extract specific Portion from logo

Tags: logo, corel-draw

Link to the [CDR file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2gbCpfaNIgnCHXRrlstCLk45oWb5bhN/view?usp=share_link)

I have this logo and I just want the complete rings from its background. Is it possible? I tried but the rings are broken midway.

[image]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V2gbCpfaNIgnCHXRrlstCLk45oWb5bhN/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Please include logo image directly into the post

Comment: If you know how to include cdr file please let me know

Comment: @sushilsoni - for future reference, when you can't include a particular file format in a question as an image, just take a screen shot of it while it's open in your application, and share that image. I've added it for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logo can be imported to Inkscape. Looks like the artist has made it difficult to edit. All construction curves and invisible areas are removed and curves are converted to strokeless closed shapes. That's logical, because

1. He obviously sells completed products, not starting points for further edits; see the note in the end of the answer.
2. All redundant data would increase the possibility of poor appearance in some not so well implemented software environments.

These are your shapes:

[image]

It looks like the artist has created an interpolated (a.k.a. blended) curve set which contains 4 intermediate steps between a circle and the longest ellipse, placed them so that there's one common point in the bottom where all curves are horizontal, rotated them to different angles around that point and finally rotated the whole set clockwise.

There's no automatic way to combine the splinters to the original single stroke no fill curves. It's also extremely difficult to repeat the guessed drawing process above, because there's so many parameters which should be guessed exactly.

Trying to draw 2 extreme curves on your image and making a blend directly might work if one had somehow more clever blend than Inkscape's path interpolate. There the result is a mess, because the tool doesn't understand the rotation and curve form differences  simultaneously. CorelDraw may have the needed more clever blending, but I do not have it.

Inkscape offers another way - not to make a mathematically perfect reconstruction, but a way to redraw it maybe visually well enough. The curves seem to have one common point. I drew the green line to memorize its place as the line endpoint. Then I drew with the pen a 5-gon through 5 points on the longest ellipse. The points are distant from each other for a good result:

[image]

Path effect "Ellipse from points" is inserted:

[image]

Making the same to all curves gives this:

[image]

It's a little off because the common point was guessed poorly and the corners of the 5-gons were clicked with no zoom in. Snapping to the orange shape cannot be used, because the corners must be in the middle of the orange curve width.

But the result can be good enough - at least after adjusting some corners a little with the node tool. They can be moved and its effect to the ellipses can be seen in live.

Applying to all ellipses Path -> Object to path fixes the effect and makes the ellipses plain single stroke paths which have no effects. Saving as plain SVG makes them usable elsewhere.

Note: Artists often do not like if someone makes new versions of their works. They often put it as written into the licenses or signed agreements. In many countries the law prohibits others automatically making new versions if the maker of the original hasn't sold his rights nor hasn't explicitly written that making new versions is allowed. Check carefully do you have the legal right to reuse the work in the way you planned.

Comment: There is no issue of rights because the artist made the logo of organization is not there. i am working in the organization and i need this to make something for organization itself.

Comment: Well thanks for the explanation. :) it will help.

Comment: @sushilsoni that does not make it ok to do thats entirely dependent on contract terms and your local law. But yeah we will take your word on it.